# Solve the equation $2^{x^2 + x} + \log_2x=2^{x+1}$

Tags: logarithms, real-numbers

> Solve the equation $2^{x^2 + x} + \log_2x=2^{x+1}$ where $x$ is real.

I tried to use derivatives, without success.
It's obvious that $x=1$ is solution.

Also, if $x \gt 1$ then $2^{x^2 + x} \gt 2^{x+1}$ and $\log_2x \gt 0$ therefore the equation has no solutions $x \gt 1$.

Comment: Hint: try some easy test values for x

Comment: @WilliamStagner Probably x=1 is the unique solution

Comment: @egreg: Thanks; that was a misstep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly, for $0 <x<1$, we have $2^{x^2+x} <2^{x+1}$ and $\log_2{x} <0$

So, $x=1$ as for $\log_2{x}$ to be defined we must $x>0$

Comment: Yes, I've seen this also. I was about to write about it.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Sorry, but you didn't post it, so I answered.

Comment: It's OK, your answer solve the equation.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $x=1$ is a solution. Let's look at two cases: $x>1$ and $x<1$.

If $x>1$, then $\log_2x>0$ and $x^2+x>x+1$, which implies that $2^{x^2+x}>2^{x+1}$. It's impossible.

If $0<x<1$, then $\log_2x<0$ and $x^2+x<x+1$, which implies that $2^{x^2+x}>2^{x+1}$. It's impossible.

In summary, we only have one solution $x=1$.